# Change the frequency of a digital pwm on Arduino Uno rev 3

Tags: arduino, pwm

I am trying to change the frequency of the digital pwm pin #9 on an Arduino Uno to 70hz. I have found some code examples for changing a pins frequency, but nothing is very clear. Can someone please explain this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Atmel ATMega Pulse-width modulation (PWM) hardware capabilities primarily supports changing the duty cycle. The frequencies can only be selected from a few fixed choices.

There is a very good and detailed explanation at arduino.stackexchange.com. Check out the the post: [How can I set two PWM at two different frequencies?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/4337/how-can-i-set-two-pwm-at-two-different-frequencies/4338#4338).

Comment: Not true, you can change frequency using TIMER1 with phase and frequency correct mode. You can output frequencies from 0,119 to 4MHz. [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41769490/4932683)

Answer (score 0):

You can change pin 9 PWM to 70Hz by changing IRC1 anc OCRA1 values.

```
    double freq = 70.0;    // Set frequency to 70Hz

    // Set Timer1 to phase and frequency correct mode. NON-inverted mode
    TCCR1A = _BV(COM1A1) | _BV(COM1B1); 

    // Set Timer1 prescaler to clk/8 (outputs from 15,259Hz to 500000Hz
    TCCR1B = _BV(WGM13) | _BV(CS11);

    //ICR Register, which controls the PWM total pulse length
    double icr = 8000000.0/8.0/freq; //ICR1 = (clk/2)/tmr_prescaler/freq.
    ICR1 = round(icr); // defines total PWM length in clock/8 

    // Now to change the PWM output value (duty cycle):
    double pwm_duty = 50.0 // Set PWM duty cycle to 50% (higher precision)
    // OR (delete line above or below)
    double pwm_duty = 120 /255.0; // is the same as analogWrite(9, 120)

    //OCR Registers, which control the PWM duty cycle.
    OCR1A = round(icr * pwm_duty/100.0);
    OCR1B = round(icr * (100.0-pwm_duty)/100.0);
```

> TIP:  You can use other freq values for other frequencies.
>
> Just remember that the higher the frequency, lower the duty cycle resolution will be.

NOTE:
Any Arduino code that uses TIMER1 won´t work after this (or will work erratically). Arduino uses TIMER1 for Servo library.